# apache restricting bandwidth

Tags: apache, xampp

Ive been looking around the web without much success.

I am running a local xampp (1.7.0) installation and a web app that i have developed that backups up my file and send them to an FTP server. The problem is that apache seem to be using only a limited amount of my bandwidth and i am unsure why this is happening.

It usually doesn't get above 64KB/s but i know that my current broadband will allow over 1MB/s which is a massive difference. Also if i use my FTP program to login to the server it will let me download in excess of 500KB/s. Does anyone know how i can get around this cos my backups are very big files and take hours to copy at 64KB/s?

Thanks Mic

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing download and upload speeds: "if i use my FTP program to login to the server it will let me download in excess of 500KB/s."

Are you perhaps on a 1Mb/64Kb ADSL or cable connection?

Comment: no im not don't worry... i am on broadband cable 100Mb/10Mb, 
i did word that poorly though. If i can download and upload from that server at 500KB/s then why can apache not do the same?